# Cannot delete outdated artifact from ivy cache with IvyDE plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, caching, ivy, ivyde

If I try to resolve snapshot dependencies of Ivy then I receive the follow error on the ivy console:

> Couldn't delete outdated artifact from cache: C:\Users\xyz.ivy2\cache\shared\foo\jars\foo-2.2.jar
>
> Error on resolve of ivy.xml in MyProject: Impossible to resolve dependencies of bla#myproject;working@xyz

IcyDE reported also that this dependency can not resolved anymore. The cause is that some plugins has a ClassLoader which hold a lock on the jar files.

Are there any ivy settings to write a to a new file location for snapshot artifacts and delete old artifacts like Gradle it do?

Answer (score 1):

Close eclipse, try deleting that artifact manually.

There may be a scenario where a prompt says that some other application may be using that resource. In that case, try stopping that application from the Task Manager and then delete the artifact.

If that doesn't stop the usage of the resource, try restarting the computer, and then delete it.

Restart eclipse.